# neo4j how to work with two match

Tags: neo4j, match, cypher

I have two queries.

First query is

```
match (user)-[r:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
```

Second query is

```
match (chatitems)-[r:PartOf]-(teamschat)-[s:OwnedBy]-()
```

I want to return the first 3 users from the first query

And to return the first 3 teams from the second query

The goal is to check if users from first query have the  teams of second query

My neo4j query is

```
match (user)-[r:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
with user.id as uid,chatitems.id as chatid
order by uid desc
with collect([uid])[..3] as users,collect([chatid])[..3] as chats
UNWIND users AS idusers
match (chatitems)-[r:PartOf]-(teamschat)-[s:OwnedBy]-()
return idusers
```

This query return

**Returned 133239 rows in 1360 ms, displaying first 1000 rows**

But I execute the query

```
match (user)-[r:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
with user.id as uid,chatitems.id as chatid
order by uid desc
with collect([uid])[..3] as users,collect([chatid])[..3] as chats
UNWIND users AS idusers
return idusers
```

idusers returned are right

**Returned 3 rows in 539 ms.**

How can I relate these two queries ?

Comment: Can you clarify your intent, with regard to the second part your query with teams? Are you trying to get the top 3 teams in some kind of order and see if any of the users in your first query are in them? Or are you trying to see if the 3 users from your first query have a team owned by someone? Or if they're in the same team? A better expression of what you're trying to do can help us give more accurate answers.

Comment: I want to get top 3 teams in desc order and see if any of the users are in them

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to collect both the top 3 users and the top 3 teams and then unwind over each collection. Something like this:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:CreatesChat]->(chatitems:Chat)
WITH user ORDER BY user.id DESC LIMIT 3
WITH collect(user) AS users
MATCH (chatitems:Item)-[:PartOf]->(teamsChat:Team)-[:OwnedBy]-()
WITH users, teamsChat ORDER BY teamsChat.id DESC LIMIT 3
WITH users, collect(teamsChat) AS teams
UNWIND users AS user
UNWIND teams AS team
MATCH p=(chatitems:Item)-[:PartOf]-(team)-[:OwndedBy]-(user)
RETURN p
```

Comment: I'm rather confused by your use of collect() and unwind here, especially where you collect teamsChat as teams and immediately unwind it. Likewise you've collected user, done nothing but pass it along with WITH, then unwound it. Am I missing something important here about what UNWIND is doing? Or is there some reason that passing along matched rows is frowned upon? Won't you get the same answer if you remove the collects and unwinds?

Comment: Ugh. Okay, I think I see the problem. If we simply pass along the rows, they match up to the other parts in the WITH and are affected by LIMIT, instead of being independent of it. So in order to preserve the limited rows from one part of the query, we need to protect it from the limit in the later part of the query by collecting it, and unwinding it after. Any other situations like this to be aware of? Any other ways to isolate order and limit operations so we can pass through previous results without change? Also, what's the reason for collecting teamsChat, as there isn't a limit here?

Comment: Yeah that's right. There's an explanation of limit+collect in this [post](https://neo4j.com/blog/common-confusions-cypher/). I think you're right about the second collect/unwind teams, probably isn't necessary, but I think it helps show explicitly what is going on.

Comment: Tricky! Thanks for the link!