# Neo4j match don't return rows

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I work with neo4j cypher

I have two relations

```
MATCH (user)-[:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
MATCH (chatitems)-[:PartOf]->(teamsChat)-[:OwnedBy]-()
```

With the first query I got the users and chatitems.
And with the second query I got the teams.

I want to check if the users first query have the teams of the second query.

I wrote this query

```
MATCH (user)-[:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
WITH user as users ,chatitems as chats ORDER BY chatitems.id DESC LIMIT 10
WITH users,collect(chats) AS chats1
with users, chats1, collect(users) as users1
MATCH (chatitems)-[:PartOf]->(teamsChat)-[:OwnedBy]-()
WITH users1, chats1,teamsChat ORDER BY teamsChat.id DESC LIMIT 3
WITH users1, chats1, collect(teamsChat) AS teams
UNWIND teams AS team
UNWIND chats1 AS chatid
unwind users1 as userid
return userid, chatid, team
```

Results are

```
userid,chatid,team
"{""id"":789}","{""id"":65090}","{""id"":62531}"
"{""id"":789}","{""id"":65090}","{""id"":62531}"
"{""id"":656}","{""id"":65092}","{""id"":62531}"
```

To check if users have the teams of second match, I added

```
MATCH (user)-[:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
WITH user as users ,chatitems as chats ORDER BY chatitems.id DESC LIMIT 10
WITH users,collect(chats) AS chats1
with users, chats1, collect(users) as users1
MATCH (chatitems)-[:PartOf]->(teamsChat)-[:OwnedBy]-()
WITH users1, chats1,teamsChat ORDER BY teamsChat.id DESC LIMIT 3
WITH users1, chats1, collect(teamsChat) AS teams
UNWIND teams AS team
UNWIND chats1 AS chatid
unwind users1 as userid
MATCH p=(chats)-[:PartOf]-(teams)-[:OwndedBy]-(users)
RETURN p
```

This query returns no rows.

How do I have to use the users1,chats1 and team that I got before in MATCH

MATCH p=(chats)-[:PartOf]-(teams)-[:OwndedBy]-(users)

**EDITED:**

I checked some queries.

I have the query(chatitems and teams)

```
MATCH (chatitems1)-[:PartOf]->(teamsChat)-[:OwnedBy]-()
WITH chatitems1 , teamsChat ORDER BY teamsChat.id DESC LIMIT 3
return chatitems1,teamsChat

chatitems1,teamsChat
"{""id"":64990}","{""id"":62531}"
"{""id"":63247}","{""id"":62531}"
"{""id"":60211}","{""id"":58852}"
```

After I executed the query

```
MATCH (user)-[:CreatesChat]-(chatitems)
WITH user ORDER BY user.id DESC LIMIT 10
MATCH (chatitems1)-[:PartOf]->(teamsChat)-[:OwnedBy]-()
WITH user,chatitems1 , teamsChat ORDER BY teamsChat.id DESC LIMIT 3
return user,chatitems1,teamsChat
```

I want to see users query 1 and chatitems, teamsChats query 2. The result is

```
user,chatitems1,teamsChat
"{""id"":65098}","{""id"":64990}","{""id"":62531}"
"{""id"":65098}","{""id"":63247}","{""id"":62531}"
"{""id"":65097}","{""id"":64990}","{""id"":62531}"
```

Do neo4j a product cartesian?

Comment: You're doing several collects() and unwinds and I can't understand why, they don't seem to be doing anything for you. Can you add to your description your understanding of what you think it's doing, and why it's needed? Also, this seems like a continuation of the problem in a previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38294427/neo4j-how-to-work-with-two-match) for which you've left no comments on the answers given. Some feedback there might help us refine our answers instead of having to create another question.

Comment: I think that only need users, chats and teams collection to check if users have teams. Perhaps I don't need unwind. But I don't know how to use this collections in MATCH p=(chats)-[:PartOf]-(teams)-[:OwndedBy]-(users). When I do this match chats, teams and user have the collections values before get?

Comment: My mistake here, for some reason I was thinking that LIMIT and ORDER BY could be applied to a part of a WITH like a subquery, instead of affecting all elements within the WITH. Collect() is needed to preserve results from one part of the query from being affected by certain operations in later parts of the query, and then restored with UNWIND when needed later on.

Comment: I checked some queries. I don't understand some results. I edited my results